# php-sql limit query per category

Tags: mysql, limit, categories

I wanted to limit my query per category, I've seen a lot of same topic here but too complicated so I will ask another.

for example I have

```
id       title        category
1        one          number
2        two          number
3        three        number  
4        four         number
5        a            letter
6        b            letter
7        c            letter
```

and I wanted to limit my query, let say 2 per category so I have on my output like these

```
one
two

a
b
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: What kind of a database are you using?

Comment: @Robert I am using phpmyadmin powered by cpanel

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from diff topic
I'll post it here for others who will drop in this same question

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
       table.*,
       @rn := CASE WHEN @category=category THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
       @category := category
    FROM table, (SELECT @rn := 0, @category := NULL) AS vars        
    ORDER BY category
) AS T1
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Created using [this link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), there's an explanation there. This also works for a large number of categories, but beware, it can become *very* slow without the right keys defined.

```
set @num := 0, @category := '';

select title, category, @num := if(@category = category, @num +1, 1) as row_number,
@category := category as dummy

from test
group by category, title
having row_number <=2;
```

Comment: I'm newbie here  ... where do I need to put "set num := 0, category := ''; "
I got error over this line

Comment: Are you trying to do this through PHP? With PHPMyAdmin you can just put it in the SQL box.

Answer (score -3):

Tell me if i'm getting you right -
That's the sql -

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,2
```

What I did is this: Select all the items in categories table and order it by the id row, limit it for two results only and order it from the beggining